# workaround for k-means to use levenshtein distance in scikit?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, knn, levenshtein-distance

I have tried to apply a custom distance to my kNN model for the reasons I detail below.

Here is my metric:

```py
def distance_fun(df, text_feat, num_feat):
    # len(text_feat) levenshtein
    # len(num_feat) euclidian
    # rest dice
    num_indices = list(range(len(text_feat), len(text_feat) + len(num_feat)))
    cat_indices = list(range(len(text_feat) + len(num_feat), len(df.columns)))
    def the_func(x, y):
        text_dist = np.sum([lev.distance(x[i],y[i]) for i in np.arange(start=0, stop=len(text_feat))]) / len(text_feat)
        num_dist = euclidean(x[num_indices],y[num_indices])
        cat_dist = dice(x[cat_indices],y[cat_indices])
        return text_dist + num_dist + cat_dist
    return the_func
```

and here is my call to the NearestNeighbors model:

```py
knn = NearestNeighbors(n_neighbors=10,
                       algorithm='auto',
                       metric=metric,
                       ).fit(tranches_transformed)
```

where `tranches_transformed` contains text in the first column and floating point values everywhere else (combination of numerical features and OHE features)

My text value are names so there is no point trying to find meaning or sentiment in them. I would still like to group similar names together (very importantly I would like identical names to be very "close" together).

I realize all values in the scikit implementation of k-means needs to be floating values so how would one work around that limitation in my specific case ?

Comment: example: column name 'name' and value: name1, name2. name3, name1.  would you like convert names to number?  column name 'name' and value: 1, 2. 3, 1?

Comment: I do not want to OHE and would like to avoid countvectorizer as well because it would create so many columns which are not necessary when really all i want to do is calculate levenshtein on simple strings.

Comment: if you have small strings, you can encode the string with something like that:
ord(l[0]) + 26*ord(l[1]) + .... and so on. Then in  knn, restore the original string. I used 26 because I supposed that you have english alphabets only. Another way, is to use a vocab dictionary and pass their indices.

Comment: you can find most used word, after the find you can add and condition columns. example if you want word "good", you can add column and set condition,  if row contain word "good"  write  "1".   in this case you do not many columns.

Comment: @coder00 thks for your comment - do you have an example of it coded somewhere ? a github repo or something similar ?
Alternatively a white paper describing the method ?

Comment: I don't have a code example. However, they are easy to implement. In first scenario, you only need to know number of unique letter and encode the word using this base. In the second scenario, you just need to add the unique words to a dictionary and use this dictionary to retrieve the word. try to implement them, if you didn't success post a question and I will be glad to help